# How do I increase axle speed using gears

Tags: gears

How do I increase speed of my output axle 24 times using 8, 16, 32, and 64 tooth gears using LEGO Mindstorms components? I checked [Sariel's website](http://sariel.pl/) but it was no help.

Comment: This is binary arithmetic at heart, you have powers of two tooth counts in your question (but you can't get those from Lego) and since 24 isn't a power of two it's going to take a non-trivial mechanism to get it. You could use a brick-built differential, for example... except where do the gears come from.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with the gears you've listed, but I'm not sure that you've listed the proper gears. I don’t believe that 32 or 64 tooth gears exist. I at least don't have any.

You can do this by combining common 8, 16, and 24 tooth gears. The following gives 3:1 × 2:1 × 2:1 × 2:1 = 24:1.

[image: gearing image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the output speed by 24 times using a classical gear system, and the gear teeth you specified, because 24 is not a product you can make from 2, 4, 8, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125.

You CAN, however make a CVT, which takes two input speeds and divides them to give an output.

Answer (score 0):

jncration is correct.

Sometimes the gears on axles helps.

[image: 24/8 times 16/8 times 16/8 times 16/8 = 3 X 2 X 2 X 2 = 24]